# UseState not updating Component property

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I'm playing with a react-countdown-circle-timer and useState.
I'm trying to add a button to start / stop and I'd like when I stop the countdown to reset to initial value. However, the stop happens, but the time is not reset, unless I navigate to another item and back. I'm new with react and I'm not having a complete understanding of how useEffect and useState works. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
import { Card, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const formatRemainingTime = (time) => {
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  if (seconds < 10 && seconds > -1) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};

const renderTime = ({ remainingTime }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.timer}>
      <div className={classes.text}>Remaining</div>
      <div className={classes.value}>{formatRemainingTime(remainingTime)}</div>
      <div className={classes.text}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

function MainItem(props) {
  const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const myDuration =
      parseInt(props.item.red.split(":")[0]) * 60 +
      parseInt(props.item.red.split(":")[1]) +
      30;
    setTotalDuration(myDuration);
  }, [props]);

  const startHandler = () => {
    setTimerOn(true);
  };
  const stopHandler = () => {
    setTimerOn(false);
  };

  const resetHandler = () => {
    setTimerOn(false);
    setTotalDuration(totalDuration)
  };

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={startHandler}>Start</button>
                  <button onClick={stopHandler}>Pause</button>
                  <button onClick={resetHandler}>Reset</button>
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col className={classes.timer_wrapper}>
                <CountdownCircleTimer
                  key={totalDuration}
                  isPlaying={timerOn}
                  duration={totalDuration}
                  size={300}
                  strokeWidth={20}
                  trailColor={"#363537"}
                  colors={[
                    ["#42b0f5", 0.5],
                    ["#42b0f5", 0.01],
                    ["#2bb32b", 0.2],
                    ["#2bb32b", 0.01],
                    ["#eeee60", 0.2],
                    ["#eeee60", 0.01],
                    ["#ff4a2e"],
                  ]}
                  onComplete={() => [true, 1000]}
                >
                  {renderTime}
                </CountdownCircleTimer>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
export default MainItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React can realize, that you don't actually change `totalDuration`. Therefore, no event is triggered to update the key prop in the `CountdownCircleTimer`.
You should create another key like

```js
const [key, setKey] = useState(false)
...
<CountdownCircleTimer key={key} ... />
```

A function, that resets the timer would be

```js
const reset = () => setKey(val => !val)
```

That way, every time `reset()` is called, `val` is changed and therefore an update on `key` is triggered.

Comment: Fantastic. I wouldn't have thought of that ever. In order to actually make it work, I had to set different key in the useEffect as well in order to load the totalDuration, but with your answer it's working perfectly. Thank you so much! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

@vektor-hector, thanks . wasted too much time to solve same problem.
there were a lot of solution way but there is no easier then yours.
by the way, other solutions didn't help me.

```
<CountdownCircleTimer
    key={key}
    isPlaying={key}
    duration={duration}
    size={75}
    colors={["#004777", "#F7B801", "#A30000", "#A30000"]}
    colorsTime={[50, 30, 15, 0]}       
    
    onComplete={(totalElapsedTime) => {          
       setKey(prev => !prev);
        showConfirmDialog();
      return { shouldRepeat: true, delay: 1} 
    }}
    updateInterval={1}        
>

const showConfirmDialog = () => {
  return Alert.alert(
    "Are you sure",        
    [
      // The "Yes" button
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => { 
         setKey(prev=>!prev);
        },
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        onPress: () => {
          navigation.navigate('FirstPage');
        },
      },
    ]
  );
};
```